# Laravel Eloquent foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables with foreing key that have another foreing key to other table and i need to join with eloquent this 3 tables.

I have the tables :

```
Films
 - ID
 - FilmsName
FilmsTags
 - FilmID
 - TagID
Tags
 - ID
 - Tagname
```

In the Eloquent mode i have:

```
Films
 public filmstags_items(){
   return $this->hasMany(FilmsTags::class, 'FilmID', 'id');
 }

FilmsTags
 public film_item(){
  return $this->hasOne(Films::class, 'id', 'FilmID');
 }

 public tag_item(){
  return $this->hasOne(Tags::class, 'id', 'TagID');
 }

Tags
 public filmstags_items(){
  return $this->hasMany(FilmsTags::class, 'TagID', 'id');
 }
```

Can i make something like this on my eloquent model Films to join the tables?

```
public join_all(){
  return $this->hasMany(FilmsTags::class, 'FilmID', 'id')->hasOne(Tags::class, 'TagID', 'id');
}
```

If not, please tell me how to do it with eloquent. I know i can make a join sentence with SQL but i want to learn eloquent.

Thank you.

Comment: read the laravel docs. Note: model should be in a singular form

Comment: The relationship between Film and Tag (singular model names) should be a `belongsToMany()`, with `FilmTag` being an intermediary (pivot) table that doesn't need a model. Read up on the Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: To use a query you could use $film->with('filmstags_items.tagitem')->get() will return a collection of films which has filmtags with tagitem

Answer (score 0):

At film model:

```
public function direct_film_tags()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Tag::class, FilmTag::class, 'FilmID', 'TagID');
}
```

You can call like that:

```
Film::with('direct_film_tags')->all();
```